# How could I solve that xLabelAngle doesn't work in morris js

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

```
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar1',
        data: [<?php echo $data_graph_bar; ?>],
        xkey: 'product',
        ykeys: ['sellingcount'],
        labels: ['Product', 'Sellingcount'],
        barRatio: 0.4,
        barColors: ['#26B99A', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
        xLabelAngle: 35,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your data `data_graph_bar`? Please elaborate your question, it's impossible to resolve your issue without more details.

Comment: <?php 
 if (!empty($bselling_products)) {
  $data_graph_bar = '';
  foreach ($bselling_products as $graph_val) { 
   $data_graph_bar .= "{ product: '".$graph_val["p_name"]."', sellingcount: ".$graph_val["product_order_count"]." },";
                 
   }
 } 
  $data_graph_bar = substr($data_graph_bar, 0,-1);      
?>

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your PHP generates...you should post the data returned by your PHP like `{date: "2017", a: 3, b: 0}, {date: "2016", a: 4, b: 10}`